# Can some transformation of a function always be found such that it has a specified integral?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Say that I've got a measurable function $\mathcal L({\bf x})$ that takes in some values ${\bf x} \in \mathbb R^{k}$ and returns a real number. $\mathcal L$  ***is bounded from above***.

Can I always find a functional $f$ which transforms my function $\mathcal L$ such that, in some sense monotonicity is preserved - if ${\bf x}$ maximizes $\mathcal L$, it should also maximize $f(\mathcal L({\bf x}))$. Moreover, $f(\mathcal L({\bf x})) \geq 0$ and:

$$\int_{...}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\mathcal L({\bf x})) dx_1...dx_n = 1 \;?$$

---

Thanks to everyone who took time to answer my question.

Comment: I assume that $\theta$ doesn't play any role here ?

Comment: Do you mean that the normalization should hold for all $\theta$ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without further assumptions on $\mathcal L$: Just consider the constant function $\mathcal L \equiv 1$. Then, for all $f$, your integral is either $0$ or $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal L$ can take negative values, then $f(0)>0$ and the integral will certainly diverge. Even with $f(\le0)=0$ the integral can diverge.

Comment: The inequality isn't strict - f can be zero.

Comment: @InfProbX: if $f$ is strictly monotonic, $f(0)\ne0$.

Comment: I've rewritten my question, hope that it makes more sense.